# Find class origin within IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to find the library specification for a class opened in the editor. I have a Maven project which is quite big with a lot of modules. When I navigate to a class which is referenced from the source code I can see a module origin in the title bar of Intellij Idea like this "HttpServlet [Maven: org.apache..."

However I am not able to see where exactly this Maven library is included from, I can guess this example above as part of an Web Service and I can think of where it is nested in, but this is a hard process sometimes especially if it is a nested include somewhere...

Comment: What do you mean by specification?

Comment: Where the class is found in the library which is a dependency and or a sub dependency in a pom.xml.

Comment: I think you are looking something like is requested here: [IDEA-178666](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178666/in-a-multi-module-maven-project-find-pom.xml-who-has-the-dependency-definition-of-the-class-that-im-viewing.) in a multi module maven project: find pom.xml who has the dependency definition of the class that i'm viewing